# Keyboard commands duplicated in spell check dialogue box

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007, spell-check

So I'm checking my document for spelling errors and I'm shown that I have a word duplicated. The dialogue box actually has TWO keyboard shortcuts with the same command.

The spelling error is "past few minutes or **so so**." I want to remove the second "so".

Alt+D takes me first to "Dictionary language:"

I've tried in vain just to disable that dropdown menu or go around it but have failed.

I want to go directly to the "Delete" button.[you can see that both commands highlighted use Alt+D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3mRo.jpg)

Comment: When you hold down the ALT key the hotkey for the commands are highlighted on the screen, usually. Is the hotkey for Delete "D", or something else? If there really are two with the exact same hotkey, does tapping the D key twice move you to the command you want? (It probably doesn't, but I just want to check)

Comment: I edited to add a screenshot in answer to your first question. The answer to your second question is yes.

Comment: Then you're probably stuck using the Tab key to move between the available commands, sadly. This is a bug, and Word 2007 is so old it will not be patched.